# Permission denied with nfs-cp command

Tags: nfs

Here is what i've done on my server:

I have add in /etc/exports:

```
/mnt2   *(insecure,rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

I have run:

```
/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
```

Here is what i've done on my client computer:

```
mount -t nfs serverip:/mnt2 /mnt
touch /mnt/tmp
umount mnt
```

It works. Great ! I can write on /mnt2 from my client computer.

Now, i have run this command:

```
 nfs-cp /tmp/somefile nfs://serverip/mnt2
```

I get this error:

> Failed to mount nfs share : mount_cb: RPC error: Mount failed with
> error MNT3ERR_ACCES(13) Permission denied(13)

I want to understand why everything works  if i mount partition and why nfs-cp command says the permission is denied...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does the user who run nfs-cp has a read permission on the exported directory?

Comment: The user who runs nfs-cp is the same than the one who try to mount: it is root